# Show all JtoolTipTexts in Java

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtooltip

With JTooltipText, I want to display all the tooltips in my frame by just clicking CTRL+ F1. But the toolips show one at a time. How can I display them all?

Comment: The answer would be no you can't do it. But I don't really understand the question. The tooltip displays for the component that has focus. What is the point of displaying all tooltips on the frame, that would confuse the user? Maybe you need to restate your requirement so we can suggest a different approach.

Comment: I want to do as like as Microsoft Word 2007 when u click ALT key so that show all the shortcut keys on the main menu. i hope to be clearly understood. any thoughts?

Comment: Menus in Swing already do this. Besides, what you want is to underline the mnemonic, not show tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows setting and has nothing to do with Java/Swing.

Check out this link which explains how to change the default in Vista. I found it also works for Windows 7.

http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/42125-always-show-menu-underline-keyboard-accelerators.html